# Froze during security update and now black screen

Tags: boot, updates

I was prompted to install security updates which. Halfway through, the screen went black and stayed that way. I let it sit that way for 30 mins until I figured that at that point it must have froze so I pressed the power button to reboot. Now, once i get through the hard drive decrypt screen, the screen goes black instead of booting into the log in screen. Any one else experience this or have a solution that doesn't involve me wiping and reinstalling thus losing my files?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these posts, They should be able to help you solve your predicament !

https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842
http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-boot-repair-ubuntu-1315203
www seravo.fi/2015/fixing-black-screen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04